# Dojo DataStore query - Using multiple parameters to search

Tags: dojo

I'm trying to query a dojo datastore object. The store has multiple objects, each one as a key titled OBJECTID with a unique value.  Is there a way to query the store like this:

dataStoreObjet.query({OBJECTID : 6990, OBJECTID: 34277, OBJECTID: 9501 } );

Right now it only returns the last object. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but it is driving me bonkers. I don't want to have to run a query for each value and then create a new set of values from all those queries if I don't have to.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The object *{OBJECTID : 6990, OBJECTID: 34277, OBJECTID: 9501 }* will only contain one value that of the last one.

This is because a javascript object is a map of properties and its value.
The {OBJECTID : 6990, OBJECTID: 34277, OBJECTID: 9501 } definition is same as

```
var obj = { OBJECTID : 6990 };
obj.OBJECTID = 34277;
obj.OBJECTID = 9501;
```

As you can see from the above the **obj** object contains the last value i.e **9501**. In effect your query to the dataStoreObjet
is

```
dataStoreObjet.query({OBJECTID : 9501} );
```

Now the solution to your problem.

You need to pass a function as a query parameter that will compare the values and return true or false for the objects to be part of the query result.

```
dataStoreObjet.query( function(object){
        return (object.OBJECTID == 6990) || (object.OBJECTID == 6990) || (object.OBJECTID == 6990)  ;
}) // Pass a function to do more complex querying
```